# Selenium Unable to Perform Operations on SVG Elements

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

I am working on a web page which consists of 6 svg tags i have to verify each svg in that one is like the following one there are totally 26 paths in this i have to locate the 18th one

html is like this

```
    <div>
    <svg>
    <circle r="80" cy="80" cx="80" stroke="#f4f4f4" fill="#ffffff" class="svg-pie-outline"></circle>
<path transform="translate(80,80)" stroke-opacity="0" stroke="#21628e" fill-opacity="0.3" stroke-width="1" fill="#1f77b4" d="M4.572014716816786e-15,-74.66666666666667A74.66666666666667,74.66666666666667 0 1,1 -73.57464370459023,-12.723321691040942L-45.98415231536889,-7.952076056900588A46.666666666666664,46.666666666666664 0 1,0 2.8575091980104907e-15,-46.666666666666664Z" class="svg-pie-slice"></path>
<path transform="translate(80,80)" stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#8598b1" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" fill="#aec7e8" d="M-73.57464370459023,-12.723321691040942A74.66666666666667,74.66666666666667 0 0,1 -34.86148247133797,-66.02869187718099L-21.78842654458623,-41.267932423238115A46.666666666666664,46.666666666666664 0 0,0 -45.98415231536889,-7.952076056900588Z" class="svg-pie-slice"></path>
<path transform="translate(80,80)" stroke-opacity="0" stroke="#ffffff" fill-opacity="0.3" stroke-width="1" fill="#ff7f0e" d="M-34.86148247133797,-66.02869187718099A74.66666666666667,74.66666666666667 0 0,1 -24.17659693792926,-70.64420196740863L-15.110373086205787,-44.152626229630386A46.666666666666664,46.666666666666664 0 0,0 -21.78842654458623,-41.267932423238115Z" class="svg-pie-slice"></path>
<path transform="translate(80,80)" stroke-opacity="0" stroke="#ffffff" fill-opacity="0.3" stroke-width="1" fill="#ffbb78" d="M-24.17659693792926,-70.64420196740863A74.66666666666667,74.66666666666667 0 0,1 -13.265702442700245,-73.47878775410526L-8.291064026687652,-45.92424234631578A46.666666666666664,46.666666666666664 0 0,0 -15.110373086205787,-44.152626229630386Z" class="svg-pie-slice"></path>

    </svg>
    </div>
```

I have the xpath to traverse till the paths but unable to locate the for each individual paths

This xpath will locate all the paths in the svg

```
html/body/div/div[1]/main/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/ol[1]/li/article/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/*[name()='svg']/*[name()='path']
```

it will traverse till all the paths unable to click on individual paths please help

didn't locate any paths in the list

```
html/body/div/div[1]/main/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/ol[1]/li/article/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/svg/path[18]
```

didn't locate any paths in the list

```
html/body/div/div[1]/main/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/ol[1]/li/article/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/*[name()='svg']/*[name()='path[2]']
```

didn't locate any paths in the list

```
html/body/div/div[1]/main/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/ol[1]/li/article/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/*[name()='svg']/*[name()='path']/*[name()='path']
```

please help

Comment: can you post URL that you are using..?

Comment: for this issue i am even trying ide for generating xpath but in that  its displaying element not located when i click on svg path elements

Comment: application is hosted on cloud and its password protected

Comment: ok..Then how can we know that xpath is right or wrong. is that xpath identifying the element in your website??

Comment: yes it is identifying till html/body/div/div[1]/main/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/ol[1]/li/article/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/*[name()='svg']/*[name()='path'] the first path i want to traverse for 3rd and 8th path means i have to click 3rd and 8th path element in svg

Comment: try to give " name='path[3]' " instead of 'path'. I hope it may work.

Comment: thanks for your help but its not working is there any other way that i can achieve this

Comment: Show us a snippet of the actual HTML that you are trying to locate.

Comment: The html you posted is not well-formed. E.g. `<path2></path>`. Do you mean that there are a bunch of `<path>` elements, and you just added the numbers as a sort of comment or label that's not actually in the HTML?

Comment: Also you need to give more detail about "didn't work" for each of the XPath expressions you tried. Did they select zero elements (no element found)? or did they select too many elements? or the wrong element? How do you know?

Comment: The second XPath in your question has `div[2]/div[3]/div[1]` where the others have `div[2]/div[3]/div[2]`. That could be the reason why that particular XPath gives the wrong result.

Comment: i have updated the question with the original the code snippet

Comment: You should consider learning XPath. Here is one resource: http://zvon.org/comp/r/tut-XPath_1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of research i got the solution for accessing the svg elements

xpath for traversing to a particular element

```
.//*[@id='global-wrapper']/div[1]/main/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/ol/li[1]/article/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/*[name()='svg']/*[name()='path' and @fill='#aec7e8']
```

add a unique attribute to access the element in my case it was fill color